# Eclipse Install New Software Not Working

Tags: android, eclipse

I just downloaded the latest version of eclipse classic from eclipse.org and i am trying to install ADK (Android Developer Kit) and i am told to download `org.eclipse.wst.xml.core` 0.0.0.

to download this i found i had to to go install new software and add the repository [Download Eclipse Juno](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/) and download the `wst.xml.core` plugin from there however all I get is pending. Its been like this for half an hour, i am only have issues with the eclipse repositorys.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**EDIT:** Issue seems to of been resolved, seems as of the repository's where lagging. Working correctly now

Comment: @jaisonDavis Just tried with https and waited a bit and it doesn't seem to make a difference same issue. :\ Everything else loads almost instantly

Comment: if its adt you want try to get the developer tools from  https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: @jaisonDavis As i said above i can't install the developer tools without  org.eclipse.wst.xml.core 0.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. The way I fixed it:

1. Help->install new software:
2. Typing: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno or http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo (if you're using version 3.7)
3. Choose the last item: WST adapter -> install

That's it!